# is there facebook provides data stream to download all public posts from all users?

Tags: facebook

Likewise twitter, Twitter provides data stream from which we can download tweets generated by users. Is there any way to download facebook posts?
I checked facebook4j but it provides only search api not streams.

Comment: No, there is not. You can only get a user’s posts, if they log in to your app and give it permission to read their posts.

Comment: CBroe I read about **Public Feed API**. will it work in my case? can I get all facebook posts from all known and unknown users on region basis or language basis?

Comment: Did you also read that this is available to a limited group of Facebook partners only, and that you can not apply for access to it …?